# how do i check that all attributes/values in a class or json object are nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I have a method that retrieves an elasticsearch query from an API and converts it to an array of JSON objects.

In some cases, the last JSON object is not a nil object, but all the attributes have nil values.

I'd like to avoid mapping over every object, but I need to filter out those JSON objects that have **all** nil values.

for example:

```
=> [#<Api::User:0x006546546
      @user_id=1,
      @height=70,
      @age=25>,
    #<Api::User:0x006546542
      @user_id=nil
      @height=nil
      @age=nil>]
```

I want to remove the all-nil object from the array either while it is in JSON format or after it is converted to an array of Api::User objects.

Is a map the only way to check all values of all objects or is there a less resource-intensive method?

Comment: Is the all-nil one always the last one?

Comment: @Joe so far yes, at least that is my working assumption. There appears to be an `if data.nil? then return klass.new end` and for some reason the elasticsearch query (or the subsequent parsing) is including nil data at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone may come up with a better way, but it seems you don't need to check all values of all objects, as the first value you check that's non-nil means that object is good.  I'd do something that checks each value up to the point that a non-nil value is found. It would also help efficiency if you can order tested fields with most likely to have a value first (e.g. `user_id` )

```
array.select do |object|
  %i(user_id height age).find do |field_name| 
    object.send(field_name)
  end
end
```

If it's only the last object that needs to be tested, then even easier...

```
array.pop if %i(user_id height age).find {|field_name| array.last.send(field_name) }
```

Comment: great point about breaking at the first non-nil variable, this is the answer i'm looking for. thanks!

Comment: `send` will only work if there are `attr_reader`s on the object.

Comment: Yes, good point @RyanSandridge... I would've edited my answer but I've just upvoted yours instead.

Comment: I ended up using `resources += resource if resource.first.instance_variables.find {|field| resource.first.instance_variable_get(field)}` because I needed to handle a variety of classes with various attributes. Ultimately, the `.find` method worked because it returned nil if all the instance variables were nil. @RyanSandridge answer used the get method so I'm not sure who should have the answer mark. Leaving it up to a dev to change as is appropriate. Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

I'd lean heavy on methods that `Enumerable` and `Object` give you. From `Enumerable` we can use `select` to choose only those elements of the array that meet some condition. That condition is that at least one of the instance variables is not `nil`, and for that we can use `any?`.

From `Object` we will use `instance_variables` to get a collection of instance variables, and we will access the value of those instance variables with `instance_variable_get`.

It would look something like this:

```
filtered_array = array.select do |object| 
  object.instance_variables.any? { |var| object.instance_variable_get(var) }
end
```

Of course `any?` is efficient in that it will stop iteration and return true on the very first "truthy" variable. As suggested by SteveTurczyn if you only need to check the last value, it is even quicker.

```
filtered_array = array[0..-2] if array[-1].instance_variables.none? { |var| object.instance_variable_get(var) }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a cleaner way, but just in case you need to map each object:

```
def are_attributes_not_nil?(my_object)
  my_object.instance_variables.map{ |attr| my_object.send(attr.to_s[1..-1]).nil? }.uniq.include? false
end
```

returns false if all attributes are nil

Comment: thanks, i did not know about the instance_variable method. even though i will likely mark a different response as answer, this is a great implementation.

Answer (score 1):

My solution involves first implementing a way to convert the objects into hashes before turning them into the JSON itself.

```
api_user_array #=> [#<Api::User:0x006546546 ... >, #<Api::User:0x006546542 ... >]
api_user_array = api_user_array.map(&:to_h).reject { |hash| hash.values.all?(&:nil?) }
# should result in an array of hashes with at least one value not nil
```

This assumes that you implement the *Api::User#to_h* method. This could be something like this:

```
def attribute_names
  %w[user_id height age]
end

def to_h
  attribute_names.each_with_object({}) { |attr, hash| hash[attr] = send(attr) }
  # assuming all attributes have a getter, otherwise
  attribute_names.each_with_object({}) { |attr, hash| hash[attr] = instance_variable_get("@#{attr}") }
end
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but im unable to modify the Api::User class. otherwise this might have been my chosen solution. also, the data comes in the form of JSON and is converted to an array of objects, not vice versa.

Comment: Ah, I misread the question in that case. But this still might give you an idea how to solve your problem.